# Symfony2 Google OAuth Login

Tags: symfony, oauth-2.0, gmail, hwioauthbundle

I have been integrating the HWIOAuthBundle in Symfony2 for Google login integration in the site;

I have followed all the steps religiously, then i got the below error while navigating to the Login Page of the site:

InvalidArgumentException: There is no extension able to load the configuration for "hwi_oauth" (in /usr/www/users/jjdqlo/Wellness/app/config/config.yml). Looked for namespace "hwi_oauth", found "framework", "security", "twig", "monolog", "swiftmailer", "assetic", "doctrine", "sensio_framework_extra", "qa", "knp_snappy", "web_profiler", "sensio_distribution"

I feel i have done something, but unable to trace as i am a novice in Symfony2

Comment: did you add `hwi_oauth` to the config.yml?

Comment: Clearly the namespace has been added to the config, that's why the error is saying that there is no extension able to load the configuration for `hwi_oauth` in the `config.yml`. Have you added the namespace to your kernel and cleared your cache?

Comment: Qoop is right, you've probably missed to register the bundle in kernel.. Did you follow [this step](https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/1-setting_up_the_bundle.md#b-enable-the-bundle)?

Comment: Now am getting classnotfoundexception : 

ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to load class "HWIOAuthBundle" from namespace "HWI\Bundle" in /usr/www/users/jjdqlo/Wellness/app/AppKernel.php line 25. Do you need to "use" it from another namespace?

I have followed all the instructions from HWIOBUNDLE git Repository

and besides i want to share another info. I have add the HWIOauthBundle in both source as well as vendor directory as i was not sure where to place it exactly.

In source folder, the file path is HWI/Bundle/[GIT_FILES], in vendor folder, hwi/oauth-bundle/HWI/Bundle/[GIT_FILES].